# Is there any way to continue in a Ticket to Ride LAN game that's gotten out of sync?

Tags: networking, ticket-to-ride

We've had this scenario play out a few times lately:

- When playing a game of Ticket to Ride on our local network, player A accidentally disconnects.
- After player A has disconnected, but before the devices belonging to the other players have noticed, player B (who goes right before player A) takes a turn.
- Now most of the devices think that it's player A's turn, but player A's device thinks that it's player B's turn. So after player A reconnects, nobody can play!

Is there any way to either roll back to player B's turn, or let player A's device know that it's really their turn now?

Comment: In my experience, no there isn’t, unfortunately you’ll just have to abandon your game.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a definitive answer, but my experience is also that there is no way to continue. The platform does not detect it automatically, and there are no controls in-game to signal these conditions and re-sync manually.

*(Ticket to Ride is not the only platform that suffers from this problem, and it is frustrating.)*